# Creating a number of variables dynamically based on a counter - PHP

Tags: php, variables, counter

I have an counter, that gives me the number of times I found a phrase in a document. And Now  I need to create a variable for each, example:

```
//Counter
$fstNameCtr = 0;
do {    
    $fstNameCtr = $fstNameCtr + 1;
} while ($firstNameRange->Execute($objFstName));
echo '$fstNameCtr';
```

The result came back with 2 instances of the phrase and I'm looking for, now I would like to create a variable for each dynamically based on the number in the counter as following like as:

```
$instance1 
$instance2
```

or

```
$instanceOne
$instanceTwo
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This would usually be a list, use:

```
$x=array();
```

Then:

```
$x[]=$newThing; //"append"
```

You can print it using `print_r`, and as it is a "list"

```
$i = 0;
while($i != count($x)) {
    echo($i.": ".$x[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Note I have used this instead of a for loop DELIBERATELY. PHP doesn't distinguish between lists and dictionaries, instead you have this horrible dictionary of numeric indices! So if you remove say the 1st thing (so $x[1]), you have a list with entries at 0, 2, 3,.....

I use this to show that I am treating the array as a list, I use for when I want the key-value pairs (or just the values)

BE CAREFUL WHEN POPPING from such a list, because then certain indices wont exist.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have a range of counters, each representing a "topic" or certain measurement. Here's a simple implementation, using a dictionary, which might be useful for you:

```
function increment(&$counters, $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $counters)) {
        $counters[$key]++;
    } else {
        $counters[$key] = 1;
    }
}
```

This can then be used with an array of counters like this:

```
$counters = array();
$phrase = "foo bar foo";
foreach (explode(" ", $phrase) as $word) {
    increment($counters, $word);
}
print_r($counters);
```

The above code will output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 2
    [bar] => 1
)
```